# How can I open the file that I created in dev and use it in user space program?

Tags: c

When I'm trying to run my code to do the user test, I'm not able to find the file, but when I look for the file in dev I can find it.

```
achraf@achraf:/dev$ ls -l charDevice_part1_0
crw-r--r-- 1 root root 240, 0 Apr 20 00:52 charDevice_part1_0
achraf@achraf:/dev$ ls -l charDevice_part2_0
crw-r--r-- 1 root root 241, 0 Apr 20 00:36 charDevice_part2_0
```

That's what I see om the terminal. And every time I run my user test program I get "file does not exist"  I don't know if I did something wrong in my usertest.c.  Can you help me please?

My usertest.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int fd;
    ssize_t readVar, writeVar;
    char myRead[10];
    char myWrite[27] = "0";

    fd = open("/dev/charDevice_part2_0", O_RDWR);

    if(fd == -1)
    {
        printf("file does not exist\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    readVar = read(fd, myRead, 10);
    printf("Number of bytes read: %zd\n", readVar);

    writeVar = write(fd,& myWrite, sizeof(myWrite));
    printf("%zd bytes were written to the kernel\n", writeVar);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to open the device read/write, but only root has read/write permissions. To make these writeable by users, the file permissions need to be `666` (read/write for owner, group, and others). I think the following `udev` rules would achieve that:

```
KERNEL=="charDevice_part1_0", MODE="0666"
KERNEL=="charDevice_part2_0", MODE="0666"
```